# how to get curl -X POST command to output the http status 200 or else?

Tags: bash, curl

I run several times this command

```
curl -X POST \
        -H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155ceed9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "$fragment" \
        https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send
```

Is that possible to ask curl to return the HTTP 200 (OK) ?

Thanks

Comment: **1** Is 200 the server's response? **2** What do you mean by "return"? Print it? Print it alongside the actual answer?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision (not an expert in curl)
1. yes
2. yes "print" alongside the actual answer

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
curl --head \
     --output /dev/null \
     --write-out "%{http_code}\n" \
     --silent \
     -X POST https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send
```

will fetch the header only, redirect the output to /dev/null, silence any progress bars, and eventually print the `http_code` (200).

If you instead want to print the content of the website alongside the HTTP returncode, then a simple `--write-out "%{http_code}\n"` will do:

```
curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" \
     -H "…" \
     -H "…" \
     -d "…" \
     -X POST https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE …>
…
<html>…</html>
200
```